# ESP8266 serial monitor spitting out garbage

Tags: serial, esp8266, nodemcu, esp

I am trying to set up a weather station, and I should just have the anemometer left. This code works fine (as far as I know).

```
// Pin definitions
const int reedSwitchPin = 2;

// Variables
volatile unsigned long lastRotationTime = 0;
volatile float windSpeed = 0.0;
const float windSpeedFactor = 2.4; // Factor to convert rotation time to wind speed

void setup() {
  pinMode(reedSwitchPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  // attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(reedSwitchPin), handleRotation, FALLING);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("hello world!");
}

void loop() {
  // Test reed switch functionality
  int reedState = digitalRead(reedSwitchPin);
  if (reedState == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Reed switch triggered!");
  }

  // Calculate wind speed based on the time between rotations
  unsigned long elapsedTime = micros() - lastRotationTime;
  if (elapsedTime > 0) {
   windSpeed = windSpeedFactor / (float)elapsedTime;
  }

  Serial.print("Wind Speed: ");
  Serial.print(windSpeed);
  Serial.println(" m/s");

  delay(1000); // Delay for 1 second before measuring again
}

void handleRotation() {
  // Record the time of the last rotation
  lastRotationTime = micros();

}
```

But when I uncomment the following line:  `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(reedSwitchPin), handleRotation, FALLING);`

it prints garbage characters on the serial monitor. Here is the full code:

```
    // Pin definitions
const int reedSwitchPin = 2;

// Variables
volatile unsigned long lastRotationTime = 0;
volatile float windSpeed = 0.0;
const float windSpeedFactor = 2.4; // Factor to convert rotation time to wind speed

void setup() {
  pinMode(reedSwitchPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(reedSwitchPin), handleRotation, FALLING);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("hello world!");
}

void loop() {
  // Test reed switch functionality
  int reedState = digitalRead(reedSwitchPin);
  if (reedState == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("Reed switch triggered!");
  }

  // Calculate wind speed based on the time between rotations
  unsigned long elapsedTime = micros() - lastRotationTime;
  if (elapsedTime > 0) {
   windSpeed = windSpeedFactor / (float)elapsedTime;
  }

  Serial.print("Wind Speed: ");
  Serial.print(windSpeed);
  Serial.println(" m/s");

  delay(1000); // Delay for 1 second before measuring again
}

void handleRotation() {
  // Record the time of the last rotation
  lastRotationTime = micros();
}
```

Comment: By garbage, do you mean that even if the anemometer is stopped, you get initially a high speed reading in the serial monitor which, continually reduces each second ?

Comment: by garbage, I mean random characters that make no sense

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Add one to your question. If the esp8266 is continually crashing then it may write to the console at a baud rate other than the one you selected. Try changing this to 115200 or  74880 in Serial.begin() and the console to see readable output.

Comment: What happens if you remove anything else but the anemometer (hardware and source code)? What does the serial window say when you change the baudrate as suggested? Please [edit] your question and add this important information.

Comment: previously, I tried every  baud rate which got me a few things, but not what I wanted, also, I don't know what you mean to remove the anemometer, and also is this issue between the serial moniter or hardware, because if it is serial moniter, I can skip this part and try to put it directly onto the website. last thing, I don't really know what you want the picture to be of

Comment: The picture I referred to would ideally be a picture/screen dump showing the serial monitor while it is displaying these "garbage characters" or, if you have found a baud rate which shows more understandable text, that instead.

Answer (score -1):

Pin 2 that is  gpio2 (D4) is not suitable for this esp8266 application because this pin must be high at boot time and your anemometer could be in either state. Try say pin 4 that is gpio4 (D2) instead or search for "best pins to use - esp8266"

A crash during boot time can result in characters being written to the serial monitor at a baud rate of 115200 or 74880.

Comment: Whoever voted down, please add a comment, why.

Comment: I wasn't the one that voted down but just saying that I thing I was using D2 not D4, at least hardware wise. should I try using D4 because D2 was the one I was using before?

Comment: @Iliketurtles   You appear to have difficulty with the two different pin numbering system in use on the nodeMcu. Search for a nodeMcu pinout diagram to see the translation between the GPIO and "D" pins. In the case here `const int reedSwitchPin = 2;` the 2 is a GPIO pin. On the nodeMcu board this is labeled D4. Try the suggestion I gave in my answer .

Comment: oh, so i should say in the code to use  const int reedSwitchPin = 4;

Comment: @Iliketurtles    Yes. `const int reedSwitchPin = 4;` is correct. So you then connect the anemometer to the pin marked `D2` on your nodeMcu board. If you have anything else connected to other pins on your nodeMcu, say a led, then temporarily disconnect these. If you still have problems then select the baud rate which gives the most understandable output on the serial console and add this output to your original question.

Comment: I have a slight problem: I have kind of soldered the pins in place and that includes an analogue pin(A0(again from the pin marking on the board)), as well as its gnd and +5v pins. I am also getting this problem where the port dropdown is greyed out

Comment: @Iliketurtles It is clearly getting worse. What you are now describing is either a problem with the IDE installation or the USB functionality of your NodeMCU. It must have worked better before for you to have seen the "garbage" characters which you reported originally. Maybe open a new topic exclusively for this latest problem.